# jqgid search controller implementation - PHP (codeigniter)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, jqgrid

I have been trying forever to get search working on the jqgrid. The online examples don't provide a controller example for the search controller side implementation. After looking at other random posts online I tried to adapt their logic to my situation. Came up with this inside my grid data controller

Every search criteria is available to me via the **$filters** variable. Inside the first for loop I can access them like **$item['field'];** , **$item['op'];** and **$item['data'];** . As is, all I get back from the server is **grouptype_id = '23'**

I just don't know how to dynamically generate the where clause for my codeigniter query. Please advise.

```
    if($this->input->get('_search')=="true"){
    $where = "";    
    $ops = array(
            'eq'=>'=', 
            'ne'=>'<>',
            'lt'=>'<', 
            'le'=>'<=',
            'gt'=>'>', 
            'ge'=>'>=',
            'bw'=>'LIKE',
            'bn'=>'NOT LIKE',
            'in'=>'LIKE', 
            'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', 
            'ew'=>'LIKE', 
            'en'=>'NOT LIKE', 
            'cn'=>'LIKE', 
            'nc'=>'NOT LIKE' 
        );
        $filters = json_decode($this->input->get('filters'), true);            
        foreach ( $filters['rules'] as $item){ 
            $searchField = $item['field'];
            $searchOper = $item['op'];
            $searchString = $item['data'];

            foreach ($ops as $key => $value) {
                if ($item['op'] == $key) {
                    $ops = $value;
                }
            }
            if ($searchOper == 'eq')
                $searchString = $searchString;
            if ($searchOper == 'bw' || $searchOper == 'bn')
                $searchString .= '%';
            if ($searchOper == 'ew' || $searchOper == 'en')
                $searchString = '%' . $searchString;
            if ($searchOper == 'cn' || $searchOper == 'nc' || $searchOper == 'in' || $searchOper == 'ni')
                $searchString = '%' . $searchString . '%';            
            $where = "$searchField $ops '$searchString' ";
        }                   
        echo $where;  

    }//end if part
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of those of you who land up here in search of a working implementation. The following code works for every search criteria no matter how complex. I am using Codeigniter, just for the record.

```
    if($this->input->get('_search')=="true"){
    $where = "";    
    $ops = array(
            'eq'=>'=', 
            'ne'=>'<>',
            'lt'=>'<', 
            'le'=>'<=',
            'gt'=>'>', 
            'ge'=>'>=',
            'bw'=>'LIKE',
            'bn'=>'NOT LIKE',
            'in'=>'LIKE', 
            'ni'=>'NOT LIKE', 
            'ew'=>'LIKE', 
            'en'=>'NOT LIKE', 
            'cn'=>'LIKE', 
            'nc'=>'NOT LIKE' 
        );
        $filters = json_decode($this->input->get('filters'), true);
        $first = true;            
        foreach ( $filters['rules'] as $item){                                
            $where .= $first ? " WHERE" : " AND ";
            $searchString = $item['data'];
            if($item['op'] == 'eq' ) $searchString = "'".$searchString."'";
            if($item['op'] == 'bw' || $item['op'] == 'bn') $searchString = "'".$searchString."%'";
            if($item['op'] == 'ew' || $item['op'] == 'en' ) $searchString = "'%".$searchString."'";
            if($item['op'] == 'cn' || $item['op'] == 'nc' || $item['op'] == 'in' || $item['op'] == 'ni') $searchString = "'%".$searchString."%'";                        
            $where .= " ".$item['field']." ".$ops[$item['op']]." ".$searchString;                
            if ($first) {
                $first = false;
            }                              
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applicant".$where; 
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);  
        $result = $query->result_array();  
        $i=0;            
        foreach ($result as $myrow){
            $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$myrow['id'];
            $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array($myrow['id'],$myrow['contingent_id'],$myrow['firstname'],$myrow['lastname'],$myrow['age'],$myrow['grouptype_id'],$myrow['registrationtype_id']);
            $i++;
         }                                                          
    }
```